# Git post hooks with jailshell, possible?

Tags: git, shell, githooks

My hosting just switched from `bash` to `jailshell` and suddenly my git hooks stopped working. Now I am wondering is it possible to achieve that with cpanel's `jailshell` ?

If not, I was automating my repo deployment to server with git hooks, is there some other way to achieve that?

**Edit:** error that I am getting is `error: cannot run hooks/post-update: No such file or directory`.

My `post-update` content:

```
#!/bin/bash
GIT_WORK_TREE=../../public_html/test git checkout -f
echo 'Uploading done!'
```

The directory mentioned in work work tree exists.

Comment: **How** did your hooks stop working? Are you getting errors? Did they stop running?

Comment: IIRC, Jailshell is a highly limited shell provided by CPanel. It is (intentionally) missing many features that are in bash, and probably doesn't support lots of things that your bash hooks depend on. I recommend you speak to your sysadmin about allowing the account with your git hooks to continue to use bash. As Etan suggests, we can't help you much here without knowing the setup and the errors.

Comment: even if I remove git work tree line it does not do nothing. Maybe I am doing something wrong